# How to kill adb.exe from task manager for Android programming?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have a problem to run my first project in android programming. the error says me to kill the adb.exe, i trying to kill it in my task manager but when I press the "kill process" in task manager, adb.exe runs again automatically. I'm using the "IntelliJ IDEA" IDE for android programming. I receive the below message:

[image: error message]

Comment: Check in commandline if adb is working properly.

Comment: no, it doesn't work.

Comment: So try to reinstall Android SDK